Can uncertainty be higher after averaging?
I remember my chemistry teacher said something about how the uncertainty for the average value shouldn't exceed the uncertainty of the uncertainty for the individual values because the reason why we average in the first place is to get a smaller uncertainty.
I'm assuming that if the uncertainty is higher you would just take the uncertainty of the individual values for the uncertainty of the average.
In my data here:

I calculated the uncertainty for the average values using max-min/2 and all my average uncertainties (the lowest one being ±0.03) seem to be higher than the uncertainty of the individual uncertainties(±0.02).
Would I just then take the uncertainty for the averaged mass lost to all be ±0.02 since it can't be higher than that value? I'm not sure but I feel that doesn't feel right replacing all the values. Does anyone know if I did something wrong?

Your average will reduce systematic error, but your individual readings contain measurement error. These aren't the same thing. It's hard to help you further because we don't know the experimental setup.

If the values are reversed, it is the sign you have evaluated them by mutually inconsistent methods.
With the provided data ranges, uncertainty of one measurement cannot be $0.02.$ It almost looks like you have confused it with the uncertainty of measurement resolution, that is always smaller than measurement uncertainty of one sample.
If we explicitly use standard deviation estimations:
$$s^2_\text{sample} = s^2_\text{res} + s^2_\text{other factors}.\tag{1}$$
When  $s_\text{sample}$ is determined, then $$s_\text{average} = \frac {s_\text{sample}}{\sqrt{N}},\tag{2}$$
where $N$ is the number of parallel samples. For three samples and normal distribution, estimations are:
$$s_\text{sample} = \dfrac{x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}}{1.67};\tag{3}$$
$$s_\text{avg} = \dfrac{s_\text{sample}}{\sqrt{3}} \approx \frac{x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}}{2.89}.\tag{4}$$
The t-value of the Student distribution for two degrees of freedom $(N-1)$ and two-tail $p=0.05$ is appropriately $4.3.$ So, the confidence interval for the average is
$$\approx  x_\text{avg} \pm  \dfrac{x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}}{2.89}\times 4.3 \\ \approx x_\text{avg} \pm (x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}) \times 1.5.\tag{5}$$
For different $N,$ the empirical formula for the denominator is
$$a = -1.513 + 3.0341\sqrt{\ln N}.\tag{6}$$

With your first set of data and the sample standard deviation as $$s= \sqrt{ \left( \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2 \right)}=0.0436$$ where $ \bar x=0.16$ is the average, produces a result which is close to your 'uncertainty of average'.
With a table of Student's t values you can now calculate the confidence limits, e.g. what is the range of data that I can be 95% confident my data will fall within and with $t = 4.303$ (for three data points at 95% or $p=0.025$) and so
$$ \text{limits on results}=\bar x\pm \frac{st}{\sqrt{n}}$$
and where $\displaystyle \frac{st}{\sqrt{n}} = 0.11$  and which gives the range $0.052\to 0.27$ which your data falls within.

IIRC, for small N like N=3  is estimation $s$ more robust, if done from the range, instead from the above classical formula for sample variance. E.g. one need about 50 samples for the relative standard deviation of the standard deviation estimation less than 10%.

@Poutnik As it happens the two methods give v similar results,  I think that the central limit theorem helps. Sampling from all sorts of distributions end up looking normal.

I have generated in Excel 100 data triplets by random normdist generator. For each triplet, I have calculated $s$ estimation by both methods. The range method was closer to the true $\sigma$ values typically in 55-65 cases from 100.

Interesting, so v similar.

Taking more measurements does not reduce error; it makes for a possible measurement of the error. The precision of the balance and the precision of sampling a reaction are entirely different and cannot be equivocated. The primary step in studying a reaction is to ensure that the measurement techniques used are equal to the job. The measurement precision of each measurement must be much less than the desired overall precision. The disjunct data suggest that something is either wrong or that more careful analytical work is needed. Start with a more precise balance and relatively calibrate all volumetric ware at least for precision and linearity. Accuracy can be established by one careful calibration. Then go thru a dummy procedure to see if the precision is within the desired tolerances. If OK run samples varying order etc and being observant. Discuss with your teacher; troubleshooting an analytical procedure requires one on one consultation.
